# Beautiful Soup 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import win_unicode_console
win_unicode_console.enable()


link = ('https://pietroalbini.io/')  
req = urllib.request.Request(link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
url = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

soup =  BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")
body = soup.find_all('div', {"class":"wrapper"})

print(body.text)
```

Hi, I have a problem with Beautiful Soup, if I run this code without ".text" at the end it show me a list of div but if I add ".text" at the end come the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "script.py", line 15, in 
>          print(body.text)
>    AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: `for div in body: print(div.text)`. find_all returns a list of items that beautifulsoup has found matching your criteria. As the error says the resulting set of objects has no attribute text, but the items inside the resulting set ( should any be found ) do.

Comment: @slayer, is that not good enough for an answer?

Answer (score 9):

`find_all` returns a ResultSet object which you can iterate over using a `for` loop. What you can do is:

```
for wrapper in body.find_all('div', {"class":"wrapper"}):
   print wrapper.text
```

Comment: actually it returns a `ResultSet` object (said directly in the error message) which may be a subclass of `set` but probably not a `list`  (you may have meant `iterable`?)

Answer (score 4):

If you'll type:

```
print(type(body))
```

you'll see `body` is `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>` It means *all* the elements that match the class. You can either iterate over them:

```
for div in body:
    print(div.text)
```

Or if you know you only have div, you can use `find` instead:

```
div = soup.find('div', {"class":"wrapper"})
div.text
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably should have posted as answer.. so as stated in the comments almost verbatim

Your code should be the following:

```
for div in body: 
    print div.text
    #python3
    #print(div.text)
```

Or some naming schema to your preference thereof.

The `find_all` method returns a generated list ( loosely using the term list here ) of items that beautifulsoup has found matching your criteria after parsing the source webpages html either recursively or non-recursively depending upon how you search.

As the error says the resulting set of objects has no attribute text, since it isn't an element but rather a collection of them.
However, the items inside the resulting set ( should any be found ) do.

You can view the documentation [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)