# BeautifulSoup .text method error: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I created a simple scraper but I have a problem with changing `ResultSet` to text. I want to get the only text without a `href` etc. When I use `find` method it works good, but when I add `find_all` as a second method it shows error:

```
numberone = soup.find("span", itemprop="house").text                      <---- this works good
print(numberone)

numbertwo = soup.find("div", class_="interesting").find_all('a').text     <---- this does not work
print(numbertwo)
```

Output for 'numberone' is good, but for 'numbertwo' it shows an error:

> "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a
>   list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when
>   you meant to call find()?" % key AttributeError: ResultSet object has
>   no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like
>   a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call
>   find()?

Maybe someone knows the solution?

Comment: That in error message there is no solution to my question :)

Comment: How come? It literally says _You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element_, how is that not enough? I'm confused...

Comment: Like you wrote it says 'probably' :)

Comment: In which case you try...?

Comment: Also, this is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091242/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-text/36091352.

Comment: i tried in many cases, don't remember it now :)

Comment: The important part of the error is *You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element*. `.text` works on individual elements, not on a whole list of elements. The next part suggests one work-around: select *one* element. The other is to *loop over the list*, and process each element in the list.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

it is because it returns a set of results, in order to print all the results you can use a for-loop like this:

```
results = numbertwo = soup.find("div", class_="interesting").find_all('a')
for result in results:
    print(result.text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very simple solution, i will read about it :)

Comment: How is the link related to the issue?

Comment: That link refers to SQLAlchemy database result sets, not a BeatifulSoup resultset (which is a subclass of list). They are very different beasts.

Comment: You are right my bad. I removed the link