# How to pull quotes and authors from a website in Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have written the following code to pull the quotes from the webpage:

```
#importing python libraries

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 500)
import time
import requests
import random
from lxml import html

#collect first page of quotes

page = requests.get("https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/05/42-essential-quotes-data-science-thought-leaders.html")

#create a BeautifulSoup object

soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup

print(soup.prettify())

#find all quotes on the page

soup.find_all('ol')

#pull just the quotes and not the superfluous data

Quote=soup.find(id='post-')
Quote_list=Quote.find_all('ol')
quote_list
```

**At this point, I now want to just show the text in a list and not see < li > or < ol > tags**
I've tried using the `.get_text()` attribute but I get an error saying

*ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'*

How can I get only the text to return?

This is only for the first page of quotes - there is a second page which I am going to need to pull the quotes from. I will also need to present the data in a table with a column for the quotes and a column for the author from both pages.

Help is greatly appreciated... I'm still new to learning python and I've been working to this point for 8 hours on this code and feel so stuck/discouraged.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'text'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091242/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-text)

Answer (score 0):

The `'html.parser'` seems to be having bit of a problem even with what I think is now the correct code. But after switching to using [`'lxml'`](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/), which this was not using, it now seems to be working:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests


page = requests.get("https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/05/42-essential-quotes-data-science-thought-leaders.html")
soup=bs(page.content, 'lxml')
quotes = []
post_id = soup.find(id='post-')
ordered_lists = post_id.find_all('ol')
quotes.extend([li.get_text()
               for li in ordered_list.find_all('li')
                   for ordered_list in ordered_lists
              ])
print(len(quotes))
print(quotes[0]) # Get the first quote
print('-' * 80)
print(quotes[-1]) #print last quote
```

Prints:

```
22
“By definition all scientists are data scientists. In my opinion, they are half hacker, half analyst, they use data to build products and find insights. It’s Columbus meet Columbo―starry-eyed explorers and skeptical detectives.”
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
“Once you have a certain amount of math/stats and hacking skills, it is much better to acquire a grounding in one or more subjects than in adding yet another programming language to your hacking skills, or yet another machine learning algorithm to your math/stats portfolio…. Clients will rather work with some data scientist A who understands their specific field than with another data scientist B who first needs to learn the basics―even if B is better in math/stats/hacking.”
```

**Alternate Coding**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests


page = requests.get("https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/05/42-essential-quotes-data-science-thought-leaders.html")
soup=bs(page.content, 'lxml')
quotes = []
post_id = soup.find(id='post-')
ordered_lists = post_id.find_all('ol')
for ordered_list in ordered_lists:
    for li in ordered_list.find_all('li'):
        quotes.append(li.get_text())
print(len(quotes))
print(quotes[0]) # Get the first quote
print('-' * 80)
print(quotes[-1]) #print last quote
```

Comment: I'm now getting....................... 
NameError: name 'ordered_list' is not defined

Comment: The code works for me. Are you sure you have copied and pasted correctly? I have included my Jupyter Notebook cell and output.

Comment: I copied and pasted it directly from the code - I feel like there is something wrong with my jupyter notebook... I had a bunch of code that I had written earlier in the notebook and it was pulling results and now I just get back [] when I re-run... I added a picture of what I'm getting when I run your code above so you can see it's not an error of inputting the code.

Comment: I see what you mean. There appears to be something wrong with your Jupyter Notebook because the line `for ordered_list in ordered_lists` defines the name `ordered_list`. Try copying the source into ` .py` file and executing it with the `python` command. I will also update the answer with an alternate coding.

Comment: Any luck with running from the command line or using the alternate coding?

Answer (score -1):

The `find_all()` method can take a list of elements to search for. It basically takes a function which determines what elements should be returned. For printing the result from the tags, you need `get_text()`. But it only works on single entity so you have to loop over the entire `find_all()` to get each element and then apply `get_text()` to extract text from each element.

Use this code to get all your quotes :- (This is updated and working)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from lxml import html

page = requests.get("https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/05/42-essential-quotes-data-science-thought-leaders.html")

soup=bs(page.text, 'html.parser')

# Q return all of your quotes with HTML tagging but you can loop over it with `get_text()`
Q = soup.find('div',{"id":"post-"}).find_all('ol')
quotes=[]
for every_quote in Q:
    quotes.append(every_quote.get_text())

print(quotes[0]) # Get the first quote
```

`Use quotes[0], quotes[1], ... to get 1st, 2nd, and so on quotes!`

Comment: This isn't returning anything

Comment: The quotes list contains all the quotes on that site! Run again, it is perfectly working

Comment: I've run several times... i don't get an error I just get nothing coming up. I'm not sure if this is an issue with my python?

Comment: have you tried `print(quotes)` or `print(quotes[0])`? What code editor do you use? **IDLE , Jupyter, PyCharm, Atom, Sublime** etc? This usually doesn't happen but restart your machine once!

Comment: I did try both print(quotes) and print(quotes[0]) - with print(quotes) I got nothing back, and with print(quotes[0]) I got two empty square brackets returned [ ] I am using jupyter

Comment: The code doesn't work using 'html.parser' with my version of Python, which is 3.8.5; `quotes` is an empty list and `quotes[0]` throws an exception.. If you switch to using 'lxml' as the parser, it does work.